# Can I use case object as method parameter

Tags: scala, case, visitor-pattern

I would like to treat every result differently without using `match`.

I wanted to make multiple method implementations but it only works for classes, using a case class instead would be too problematic.

The following approach does not work:

```
sealed trait Result

object Result {
  final case object Result1 extends Result
  final case object Result2 extends Result
  final case object Result3 extends Result
}

def doSth(result: Result)=
  consumeResult(result)

private def consumeResult(result: Result.Result1) = ???

private def consumeResult(result: Result.Result2) = ???

private def consumeResult(result: Result.Result3) = ???
```

Comment: `result: Result.Result1.type` - However, usually **pattern matching** or **typeclasses** are more common for those cases.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate fix is to use the object `type` like this:

```
private def consumeResult(result: Result.Result1.type) = ???
etc..
```

However the broader code is not going to work:

```
def doSth(result: Result) =
  consumeResult(result)
```

Function overloading happens at compile time, not run time. By the time you call `consumeResult` the run-time type is lost. The compile-time type is `Result` so it won't match any of your overloaded versions of `consumeResult`.

A **typeclass** might be the best approach:

```
trait Consume[T <: Result] {
  def consume()
}

object Consume {
  implicit object consume1 extends Consume[Result.Result1.type] {
    def consume() = {
      println("Consume1")
    }
  }

  implicit object consume2 extends Consume[Result.Result2.type] {
    def consume() = {
      println("Consume2")
    }
  }
}

def doSth[T <: Result](result: T)(implicit ev: Consume[T]) =
  ev.consume()


doSth(Result.Result1) // Prints "Consume1"
doSth(Result.Result2) // Prints "Consume2"
doSth(Result.Result3) // Does not compile, no matching typeclass
```

Comment: `def doSth[T <: Result](result: T) =` still won't compile, because it doesn't work for every `T <: Result`; e.g. for `Result` itself.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov And even if you fix it, the type resolution is done at compile time so it doesn't work :(

Comment: That's correct, the implementation above fails to do the job. 
I wonder, is there any other approach to the problem, or switching to classes is inevitable?

Comment: @syforce In what way does the (edited) answer not "do the job"?

Comment: Your implementation is correct for every specific Result subtype passed as method argument.
However consider this:
```val result: Result = Result.Result1

  doSth(result) // will not compile as there is no implicit for Result type```

Comment: @syforce That is intentional. Once you have cast to the base `trait` you have lost the compile-time type information so you can't pick the correct implementation without using a run-time test like `match` or ugly `isInstanceOf` tests, which you explicitly disallow. It is easy to create the relevant typeclass if necessary.